# Can't change PORT listen on macOS X Mojave for built-in SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, macos-mojave

macOS X Mojave 10.14.2, Kernel Darwin 18.2.0 
Want to change 22 port listening for incoming SSH connections for any from 2222x further for security reasons. 
Changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config make no sense.. 
This [Methods describing before](https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x/67616#67616) doesn't works too for me on Mojave
Any suggestions where is the port settings I can change?

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
# SSH v2
Protocol 2
Port 2222
AddressFamily inet
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

client's /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
 Host *
        Protocol 2
        Port 2222
        SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

port listening on sshd:

```
MBP:.ssh user$ > sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
    COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    launchd       1   root    8u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd153731a7      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   12u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd153798e7      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   14u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd22020067      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   20u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd2eeb3f67      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   24u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd153731a7      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   26u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd15373767      0t0  TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   28u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd153798e7      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   29u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd22020067      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   33u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd15378f67      0t0  TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   43u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd15373767      0t0  TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   44u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd15378f67      0t0  TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
    launchd       1   root   47u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd2eeb3f67      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
    kdc          87   root    5u  IPv6 0xad7e82fd15372be7      0t0  TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
    kdc          87   root    7u  IPv4 0xad7e82fd15377c67      0t0  TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Launching sshd with custom port via custom launchctl plist stopped working for me when I upgraded to Monterey (Oct 2021).. Editing /etc/services and launching sshd by enabling standard "sharing -> remote login" preference did work (but see caveats below).  See also https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/qhr5d0/psa_nondefault_ssh_port_on_monterey_fixed/

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/q/18761/902296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to change the default port 22 to port 22222

Open a terminal window

Edit the `/etc/services` file
Enter:
`sudo vi /etc/services`
You'll be prompted for you password and obtain an elevated security privilege to make changes.

Use the slash command to find the ssh service `/ssh`.   There will be two entries, one for `tcp` and the other for `udp`

**ssh   22/udp  # SSH Remote Login Protocol**
**ssh   22/tcp  # SSH Remote Login Protocol**

Change the number 22 in both cases to 22222 or your desired port number.

Save the changes with `:w`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You need to recycle the **ssh** daemon.  Depending on your system setup, **ssh** may not be running.  If it is not, the first command will fail; ignor it and move on to the second to start **ssh**.

Enter the following command to stop it:
`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

Now enter the following command to start SSH again:
`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

Verify you can access the system by logging in with ssh using this command:
`ssh localhost -p 22222`

To put the system back, redo the above steps and change the ssh port back to 22.

Comment: Such simple is that. Definitely easy and successful result. Thank you Hogstrom
But port in command: ssh -p 22222 localhost

Comment: problem is if you want to `ssh` out, it will also use port `22222`

Comment: To address the problem @sonjz points out, you can edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config to add "  Port 22" so that outbound ssh still uses port 22. [edit: as pointed out in another answer...]

Answer (score 4):

Listening on port 22 is handled by `launchd`, which is the equivalent of Unix's `init`, `inetd` and `cron`.  `Inetd` can be configured to listen on a port and launch the appropriate command, rather than the command starting in daemon mode, same with `launchd`.

You'll notice that if you run a `ps -ax | grep sshd` none of them are listening on port 22.  You'll also notice that if you run an `lsof` on the `launchd` process you'll see it listening on port 22.

`launchd` is configured via a bunch of `.plist` files in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` The system directory being installed with the OS, and the non system is added after installation.

The configuration you're after is `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.openssh.sshd</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/sbin/sshd</string>
                <string>-i</string>
        </array>
        <key>Sockets</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Listeners</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>SockServiceName</key>
                        <string>ssh</string>
                        <key>Bonjour</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>ssh</string>
                                <string>sftp-ssh</string>
                        </array>
                </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Wait</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Instances</key>
                <integer>42</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
        <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
        <string>system.preferences</string>
        <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
        <string>Interactive</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you don't want it listening on port 22 anymore, you can just edit this file.  Otherwise copy it, with a different name, to `/Libary/LaunchDaemons` and edit that copy. `cp /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-alt.plist`

Edit the line just under the `SockServiceName` it is a string of the port number or port alias, hence why changing `/etc/services` works.  You can either add the numeric port you want to the array in the plist or add the numeric port you want to /etc/services with your own identifier, like `my-ssh-alt` and change to that in the plist.

If you've copied to a new plist, Load the new plist;

`sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-alt.plist`

Else reload the ssh config, which I'll just copy from the other answer;

Enter the following command to stop it:
`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

Now enter the following command to start SSH again:
`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

Comment: Launching sshd with a custom port via a custom launchctl plist stopped working for me when I upgraded to macOS Monterey (Oct 2021).  Specifically, connections in to sshd on the port are now terminated with the error 'kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer'.  Editing /etc/services still seems to work as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

To follow-up on Hogstrom's response you may want to additionally edit the /etc/ssh/ssh_config and uncomment the following :

Port 22

So when you attempt to ssh to a normal host (running port 22) that is chosen instead of the new ssh default that you set in /etc/services.

Answer (score 1):

##### Script

Just threw together a [small script](https://gist.github.com/lstellway/58c78471ce09f665dd10adb973378935) based on what has been shared here in the forum *(specifically [silicontrip](https://superuser.com/a/1661086/918318))*.

```sh
ssh_set_port() {
  # Ensure a port is specified
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    printf "No port specified...\n"
    return 1
  fi

  # Ensure original file exists
  if [ ! -f "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plistz" ]; then
    printf "SSH process definition not found in default location:\n%s\n" "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist"
    return 1
  fi

  PORT="$1"
  FIND="<string>ssh<\/string>"
  REPLACE="<string>${PORT}<\/string>"

  # Unload existing service if a file already exists
  # (errors may occur if service is already unloaded - these can be ignored))
  if [ -f "/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist" ]; then
    sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist > /dev/null 2>&1
  fi

  # Copy original SSH process definition and replace the port value
  sudo cp /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
  sudo sed -i '' "1,/${FIND}/s/${FIND}/${REPLACE}/" /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist

  # Load the service
  sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist

  printf "SSH port successfully updated to '%s'\nRun the following command to verify the port:\n\n  %s\n" "$1" "sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P"
}
```

##### Usage

You can include the logic in a stand-alone script or include it in your shell profile (eg. `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bashrc`, etc..). I have included it in my shell profile. Example usage:

```sh
ssh_set_port 2200
```

##### Note

*The `launchctl` subcommands `load` and `unload` are being deprecated, but still work in the latest version as of writing ([good reference with link to documentation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340871/450099))*.

I plan to carry this around with the rest of my shell aliases.
Thank you all for the great answers

Answer (score 0):

To add to silicontrip's answer, if you wanted both the original and new ports you can add an "Alternate Listeners" key (or any label apparently) in the Sockets section of ssh.plist:

```
...
 <key>Sockets</key>
 <dict>
     <key>Listeners</key>
     <dict>
          <key>SockServiceName</key>
          <string>ssh</string>
          <key>Bonjour</key>
          <array>
              <string>ssh</string>
              <string>sftp-ssh</string>
          </array>
     </dict>
     <key>Alternate Listeners</key>
     <dict>
         <key>SockServiceName</key>
         <string>(name of service)</string>
     </dict>
</dict>
...
```

Note that in Monterey the ProgramArguments section has changed since Big Sur (it used to call sshd directly). This resulted in a "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" if you just copied an ssh.plist file from Big Sur to Monterey.

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
      <string>sshd-keygen-wrapper</string>
</array>
```

My problem with modifying /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist is that I don't want to break the apfs seal on the volume.

I created a copy of the ssh.plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh_alt.plist with a different Label and started it with

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh_alt.plist
```

and it seems to persist across boots so far.